# fipy: 2D Laplace equation: boundary conditions not taken

Tags: fipy

```
from fipy import CellVariable, Grid2D, DiffusionTerm
nx = 20         # grid size on coordinate axes
dx = 1          # grid spacing
ny = nx; dy = dx; L = dx*nx
mesh = Grid2D(dx=dx, dy=dy, nx=nx, ny=ny)
phi = CellVariable(name = "phi", mesh = mesh, value = 0.5)
eq = (0. == DiffusionTerm( coeff=1., var=phi))
valueTopLeft = 0.; valueBottomRight = 1.
phi.constrain(valueTopLeft, where = mesh.facesLeft)
phi.constrain(valueBottomRight, where = mesh.facesRight)
eq.solve(var=phi)
print (phi.value[:])
```

What's wrong with this code?
Code produces zero solution, which is not correct.

Comment: See the docs: you need to define boundary conditions on external faces, otherwise the result is Zero.

Comment: The Dirichlet constraints as specified at left and right are fine. Top and bottom faces naturally get a zero flux condition.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [bug](https://github.com/usnistgov/fipy/issues/672) in FiPy if you specify the grid spacing as an integer. Changing to `dx = 1.` results in

```
[0.025 0.075 0.125 0.175 0.225 0.275 0.325 0.375 0.425 0.475 0.525 0.575
 0.625 0.675 0.725 0.775 0.825 0.875 0.925 0.975 0.025 0.075 0.125 0.175
 0.225 0.275 0.325 0.375 0.425 0.475 0.525 0.575 0.625 0.675 0.725 0.775
 0.825 0.875 0.925 0.975 0.025 0.075 0.125 0.175 0.225 0.275 0.325 0.375
 0.425 0.475 0.525 0.575 0.625 0.675 0.725 0.775 0.825 0.875 0.925 0.975
 0.025 0.075 0.125 0.175 0.225 0.275 0.325 0.375 0.425 0.475 0.525 0.575
 0.625 0.675 0.725 0.775 0.825 0.875 0.925 0.975 0.025 0.075 0.125 0.175
 0.225 0.275 0.325 0.375 0.425 0.475 0.525 0.575 0.625 0.675 0.725 0.775
 0.825 0.875 0.925 0.975 0.025 0.075 0.125 0.175 0.225 0.275 0.325 0.375
 0.425 0.475 0.525 0.575 0.625 0.675 0.725 0.775 0.825 0.875 0.925 0.975
 0.025 0.075 0.125 0.175 0.225 0.275 0.325 0.375 0.425 0.475 0.525 0.575
 0.625 0.675 0.725 0.775 0.825 0.875 0.925 0.975 0.025 0.075 0.125 0.175
 0.225 0.275 0.325 0.375 0.425 0.475 0.525 0.575 0.625 0.675 0.725 0.775
 0.825 0.875 0.925 0.975 0.025 0.075 0.125 0.175 0.225 0.275 0.325 0.375
 0.425 0.475 0.525 0.575 0.625 0.675 0.725 0.775 0.825 0.875 0.925 0.975
 0.025 0.075 0.125 0.175 0.225 0.275 0.325 0.375 0.425 0.475 0.525 0.575
 0.625 0.675 0.725 0.775 0.825 0.875 0.925 0.975 0.025 0.075 0.125 0.175
 0.225 0.275 0.325 0.375 0.425 0.475 0.525 0.575 0.625 0.675 0.725 0.775
 0.825 0.875 0.925 0.975 0.025 0.075 0.125 0.175 0.225 0.275 0.325 0.375
 0.425 0.475 0.525 0.575 0.625 0.675 0.725 0.775 0.825 0.875 0.925 0.975
 0.025 0.075 0.125 0.175 0.225 0.275 0.325 0.375 0.425 0.475 0.525 0.575
 0.625 0.675 0.725 0.775 0.825 0.875 0.925 0.975 0.025 0.075 0.125 0.175
 0.225 0.275 0.325 0.375 0.425 0.475 0.525 0.575 0.625 0.675 0.725 0.775
 0.825 0.875 0.925 0.975 0.025 0.075 0.125 0.175 0.225 0.275 0.325 0.375
 0.425 0.475 0.525 0.575 0.625 0.675 0.725 0.775 0.825 0.875 0.925 0.975
 0.025 0.075 0.125 0.175 0.225 0.275 0.325 0.375 0.425 0.475 0.525 0.575
 0.625 0.675 0.725 0.775 0.825 0.875 0.925 0.975 0.025 0.075 0.125 0.175
 0.225 0.275 0.325 0.375 0.425 0.475 0.525 0.575 0.625 0.675 0.725 0.775
 0.825 0.875 0.925 0.975 0.025 0.075 0.125 0.175 0.225 0.275 0.325 0.375
 0.425 0.475 0.525 0.575 0.625 0.675 0.725 0.775 0.825 0.875 0.925 0.975
 0.025 0.075 0.125 0.175 0.225 0.275 0.325 0.375 0.425 0.475 0.525 0.575
 0.625 0.675 0.725 0.775 0.825 0.875 0.925 0.975 0.025 0.075 0.125 0.175
 0.225 0.275 0.325 0.375 0.425 0.475 0.525 0.575 0.625 0.675 0.725 0.775
 0.825 0.875 0.925 0.975]
```

Comment: If this answered your question, [please accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score -1):

Thanks a lot. I should have found the problem myself. Now I am ready for more fancy things!